# DSVM GPU runs out of memory

Tags: apache, keras, gpu, azure-dsvm

I'm working on a REST API web app on the DSVM Ubuntu machine. The server runs Flask, Apache, and Keras.

I'm using a GPU machine with 56GB RAM and a single K80 GPU.

The problem is that even with a small batch size for predicting with my model, the GPU runs out of memory.

With nothing running, the 12GB GPU is using over 10GB.  Maybe this is because of a problem with Apache.

Running `nvidia-smi` shows the following:

```
|    0     38915      C   python  370MiB |

|    0     98378      C   /usr/sbin/apache2    10860MiB |
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the TensorFlow backend for Keras. TensorFlow allocates nearly all GPU memory by default to reduce potential memory fragmentation. From [the TensorFlow guide to using the GPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/using_gpu), you can limit the total memory allocated by TensorFlow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.3
set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```